# Estimated rows very wrong when using declared variables

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, execution-plan, cardinality-estimates, query-performance

I am getting *very*, *very* wrong estimates for the clustered index seek step of  this query (estimated rows is 8,637,530; actual is 74,723):

```
Declare @StartDate as date = '10/1/2014';
Declare @EndDate as date = '10/2/2014';

select Sum(Quantity)
from Daily_GC_Items
where SalesDate between @StartDate and @EndDate;
```

If I use string literals for the dates like this, the estimate is almost perfect (estimated rows is 75,337.4; actual is 74,723):

```
select Sum(Quantity)
from Daily_GC_Items
where SalesDate between '10/1/2014' and '10/2/2014'
```

Table definition:

```
[SalesDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[Store] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[GuestCheckNumber] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[ItemSequence] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[Quantity] [smallint] NOT NULL,
(Several more columns)
```

Primary Key:

```
[SalesDate] ASC,
[Store] ASC,
[GuestCheckNumber] ASC,
[ItemSequence] ASC
```

What are the possible causes for this behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *...SSMS is not running this using sp_execute so I don't think this is being caused by parameter sniffing. What are the possible causes for this behavior?*

The optimizer [cannot 'sniff' the values of local variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986.aspx), so the cardinality estimate is based on a *guess*. If you are using the original cardinality estimator, the fixed guess for `BETWEEN` is 9% of the table's cardinality.

If using the new [cardinality estimator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600374.aspx), the guess is computed using [exponential backoff](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/sql-plan/cardinality-estimation-for-multiple-predicates), applied to the separate `>=` and `<=` comparisons that `BETWEEN` is shorthand for. The guess for `>=` and `<=` is 30% (0.3) each, so the overall guess is `0.3 * SQRT(0.3) = 0.164317 (* table cardinality)`.

You have to decide between [caching and reusing a reasonable plan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966425.aspx) for all future variable values, or recompiling on each execution to generate a new plan for the specific values each time. The second option makes use of the [Parameter Embedding Optimization](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options), which is only applied if you use the query hint `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. There is an obvious trade-off to be made here, between the cost of recompiling each time (the resulting plan is never cached for reuse) and using a not-quite-optimal reused plan for each execution.

There are additional options for you to consider, including specifying typical values in an `OPTIMIZE FOR` hint; see my [SQLPerformance.com article](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options) for details.